# How to use method that returns CompletionStage inside thenCombineAsync

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8

I have 3 functions that return `CompletionStage`. Let's say that they looks like:

```
CompletionStage<A> funcA();
CompletionStage<B> funcB();
CompletionStage<C> funcC(A a, B b);
```

Now I would like to write fuction `funcD` that returns `CompletionStage<C>`. Result is computed by `funcC` and params cames from both `funcA` and `funcB`. Now the question is how to do it properly?

My attempts after reading documentation looks like this, but I'm not sure if it is proper usage. The problem is that after `thenCombineAsync` I receive `CompletionStage<CompletionStage<C>>` and the last line looks like ugly workaround to extract proper result. Can it be accomplished any better?

```
CompletionStage<C> funcD() {
    CompletionStage<B> completionStageB = funcB();
    return funcA()
        .thenCombineAsync(completionStageB, (a,b) -> funcC(a,b))
        .thenComposeAsync(result -> result);
}
```

Let's assume that method's declarations cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `thenComposeWithBoth`.  If you cannot modify method signatures, I would just leave it as is (but remove `Async` -- see below).  The only way to make this shorter is to `join()` inside the `Combine` stage:

```
funcA()
    .thenCombineAsync(completionStageB, (a,b) -> funcC(a,b).join());
```

On a separate note, you are using `...Async` methods needlessly.  Since your `funcC` returns a `CompletableFuture`, it is probably not long-running and there is no need to schedule it asynchronously.  And `result -> result` certainly does not need to run in a separate thread.

Comment: `join()` would be lovely, unfortunately it's absent in `CompletionStage` interface (now I see that I tagged my question with completable-future by mistake). It's good point about asyncs, thank you.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that it was returning `CompltionStage` rather than `Future`.  You can convert from `Stage` to `Future` with `.toCompletableFuture()`.  So, `(a,b) -> funcC(a,b).toCompletableFuture().join()`